# I made my string be repeated by the method repeat but i don't know how to make an array from what i got in output

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

```
function ipTransform(ip) {
   const arr = []
   const binNums = ip.split(".").map((x) => parseInt(x).toString(2))
   binNums.forEach(function(x) {
       if(x.length < 8) {
        const other = "0".repeat(8 - x.length) + x
     }
  })
}
```

`ipTransform("128.32.10.1")`

*How can i make my variable other an array? Now it is just 3 strings*

Answer (score 0):

I just compiled the code to ES5:

```
"use strict";

function ipTransform(ip) {
  var arr = [];
  var binNums = ip.split(".").map(function (x) {
    return parseInt(x).toString(2);
  });
  binNums.forEach(function (x) {
    if (x.length < 8) {
      var other = "0".repeat(8 - x.length) + x;
    }
  });
  return binNums;
}
```

and got a correct result.

```
> ipTransform('127.0.0.1')
> ["1111111", "0", "0", "1"]
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I need:
I need a variable other to be an array, I don't need to return bunNimus

Comment: Here is my task:
 
Take the following IPv4 address: 128.32.10.1 This address has 4 octets where each octet is a single byte (or 8 bits).
Because the above IP address has 32 bits, we can represent it as the 32 bit number: 2149583361.

Write a function ip_to_int32(ip) ( JS: ipToInt32(ip) ) that takes an IPv4 address and returns a 32 bit number.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
function ip_to_int32(ip)
{
  // split the IP
  // convert each part to binary
  // make sure its 8 bits long
  const binNums = ip.split(".").map((x) => (("00000000" + parseInt(x).toString(2))).slice(-8));
  
  // join the array and then conver to integer using parseInt
  return parseInt(binNums.join(""), 2);
}

console.log(ip_to_int32("128.32.10.1"));
console.log(ip_to_int32("10.10.10.1"));
console.log(ip_to_int32("192.168.1.1"));
```

Alternatively:

```js
function ip_to_int32(ip)
{
  return ip.split(".").map((x, i, a) => x * Math.pow(256, a.length - i - 1)).reduce((a,b) => a + b)
}

console.log(ip_to_int32("128.32.10.1"));
console.log(ip_to_int32("10.10.10.1"));
console.log(ip_to_int32("192.168.1.1"));
```

This one works because IP addresses are basically base 256. So you just need to do some math on each octet and add them.

```
192.168.1.1 => 192*256^3 + 168*256^2 + 1*256^1 + 1*256^0.
```

Comment: Thanks, did'nt know that i could make it with slice(-8) 
Thanks a lot!
Been stuck for about 3 hours.